# How do I set my iframe height to its content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am trying to set my iframe height in React since right now, the iframe height is for some reason scrolling instead of having a full height.

When I inspect my elements, my height looks fine in the  tag but in the #document tag, the height is set for some reason.

I was looking through stack overflow and I found that i can set the iframe heihgt onLoad by getting the document.body.scrollheight.

However, I am able to print out the document, but when I get the document.body, I get undefined. My code is down below.

How do i fix this? or is there a better way to set the ifram eheight to its conetnet?

```
 resizeIframe = () => {
        var iFrameID = document.getElementById('iframeThreadBody');
        if(iFrameID) {
            //console.log(iFrameID.contentWindow.document); works
           //console.log(iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body); undefined
           iheight = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollheight + 'px';
           iFrameID.height = iheight;
           //iFrameID.height = 500 +'px'; //also for some reason this doesnt work either.
        }
}
render(){
  return(
   //random code
   <iframe
      id = "iframeThreadBody"
     title = "threadBody"
     className = "iframeBody"
     srcDoc = {this.state.description}
     onLoad = {this.resizeIframe(this)}/>
   //code
)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script can only access `iframe` content DOM on the same domain origin. Cross-origin access is forbidden due to security concern. At least directly, as you still have one good way to do that: the standard [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Provided that you also have control of the target domain, otherwise you're out of luck, sorry.

To do cross-origin communication, you set up a script in your target document to query the document height, then use `postMessage` to transmit that information to the `iframe` host, which listens on the `message` event. The host then sets the height of the `iframe` accordingly. It's not very hard to do, it has excellent browser support, and it's very fast (communication is done within your computer, not going out to the network).